# grails gsp radiogroup, how to set id for each input radio field

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp, radio-group

How to set id for each input attribute in gsp grails app.

```
<g:radioGroup id="x">
   ${it.label} ${it.radio}
</g:radioGroup>
```

`id="x"` is not working

Answer (score 4):

The property `id` is not supported in the tag [radioGroup](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.2/ref/Tags/radioGroup.html).

A solution would be to generate yourself the radio group with **ids** like this:

```
<g:each in="${entities}">
    <p>${it.name}: <input id="X" type="radio" name="entityName" value="${it.value}"/></p>
</g:each>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Still Grails can support ids = [] for radio group.

Comment: @user1245222, I was unable to find support for an array of id tags, although the same technique works for values and labels.  https://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Tags/radioGroup.html